# What does the notation $\langle x^n:\; x\in G\rangle$ mean?

Tags: group-theory, notation

If $G$ is a group, what does $$G^n:=\langle x^n:\; x\in G\rangle$$ for a fixed $n\in\mathbb{N}$ mean? This should be a subgroup of $G$ but I din't know the definition of $\langle x^n:\; x\in G\rangle$, The notation is new for me.

The background of this question is, I'm interested in this [A group is divisible if and only if it has no maximal subgroup ?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1024146/a-group-is-divisible-if-and-only-if-it-has-no-maximal-subgroup) answer .

Regards

The question above is answered in the comments above, thanks! I have an additional question:

Here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_set_of_a_group wikipedia says that the elements of $G^n$ can be expressed as a finite product of elements in $S$ and their inverses  I find a description here [Subgroup generated by a set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/145442/subgroup-generated-by-a-set) ). WIth this characterisation, how to write $G^n$? I thought $\{x^nx^{-n}:x\in G\}$ first, but it doesn't make sense.

Edit 2:The additional question is clear now!!

Comment: If you have a subset of a group $S \subseteq G$, then $\langle S \rangle$ denotes the subgroup of $G$ generated by $S$.

Comment: It looks like $n$ is a fixed integer, and this means the group generated by the $n$ths powers of elements of $G$. The angled brackets, $\langle\qquad\rangle$, mean the structure (here obviously a subgroup) generated by whatever set is inside. The colon explains the use of variables much like in set construction notation.

Comment: with $S=\{x^n: x\in G\}$?

Comment: @algebra Exactly.

Comment: okay thanks. Here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_set_of_a_group wikipedia says that the elements of $G^n$ can be expressed as a finite product of elements in $S$ and their inverses  I find a description here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/145442/subgroup-generated-by-a-set ). WIth this characterisation, how to write $G^n$? I thought $\{x^nx^{-n}:x\in G\}$ first, but it doesn't make sense.

Comment: $\{x_1^nx_2^n\cdots x_r^n:x_i{\rm\ in\ }G\}$.