# a group is divisible if and only if it has no maximal subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

prove :a group is divisible if and only if it has no maximal subgroups.

Let $G$ be a group. We denote by $\Phi(G)$ the intersection of all maximal subgroups of the group $G .$ Clearly $\Phi(G)$ is a subgroup of $G$ (called the Frattini subgroup) and $\Phi(G)=G$ if and only if $G$ has no maximal subgroups. We shall use the following lemma:
 For a group $G$ we have $\Phi(G)=\bigcap_{p \in \mathbf{P}} p G$
It is clear then that $G$ is divisible if and only if $p G=G$ for all $p \in \mathbf{P},$ or equivalently, if $\Phi(G)=\bigcap_{p \in \mathbf{P}} p G=G,$ which implies $G$ has no
$p \in \mathbf{f}$
maximal subgroups.($\mathbf{P}$ is the set of all prime numbers)

and we know If a group has no maximal subgroups, then all elements are non-generators.

I want proof conversely. If a group $G$
 has no maximal subgroups then $G$
 is divisible

Comment: What is exactly your question? You want us to verify your proof?

Comment: @TPace. I want proof conversely.  If a group $G$ has no maximal subgroups then $G$ is divisible.

Comment: Would this help https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1024146/a-group-is-divisible-if-and-only-if-it-has-no-maximal-subgroup

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A group is divisible if and only if it has no maximal subgroup ?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1024146/a-group-is-divisible-if-and-only-if-it-has-no-maximal-subgroup)

Comment: @Rick. No I can't understand this answer I think this is false.

Comment: @amirbahadory Then show some reasoning why it should be false.